# Pipe non ASCII characters to file

Tags: encoding, ascii

So, this is a bit of a dumb question...
Just for fun I was trying to pipe the `doge` command into a file by using `doge > doge.txt`, but when I opened it some parts were not showing (probably because they were not ASCII characters).
Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Does it correctly display on your console without the redirect? If it does, it's likely that your viewer for the file used the wrong charset.

Comment: AFAIK, `doge` use color, so probably you got a file stuffed with bunch of ESC sequences